# Why doesn't this Ruby code get triggered?

Tags: ruby

I have this class to store bans:

```
class Bans < Hash

 def ban(ip, time, reason)
  self[ip] = {time: time, reason: reason}
 end

 def banned?(ip)
  if self.include?(ip)
   return true
  else
   return false
  end
 end

end
```

I use this elsewhere in another class:

```
  if @bans.banned?(@ip)
   // code
  end
```

The problem is that the code doesn't get triggered, even when the IP address is banned. Removing the `if` clause and just having the `// code` runs, so it must be a problem with the `if` clause, but I don't understand what I'm doing wrong (I'm new to Ruby).

Comment: This should work ok. Are you sure `@ip` is something that you’ve previously added to the hash (same format etc.)? If the `if` is evaluating to `false` then the hash probably doesn’t include `@ip`. Can you add an example of using the class where it doesn’t work as you expect?

Comment: Can you produce a runnable snippet that exhibits the problem?

Answer (score 3):

`self.keys.include? ip` should work :)

Full method:

```
def banned?(ip)
  keys.include? ip
end
```

**EDIT:**

How to use the class:

```
@bans = Bans.new()
@bans.ban('123', 12, 'because')
@bans.banned?('123') #=> true
```

Comment: It still doesn't get triggered. In another class it would be right to use `if @bans.banned?(@ip)` right? That is what I'm using :-/

Comment: Could you please add what `@bans` and `@ip` are to your question?

Comment: `@bans` is the class name right? `Class Bans < Hash` and `@ip` is a string like `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: I've edited the answer. `@bans` is just an instance variable. You can assign whatever you want there, but you have to assign it for it to be there :)

Comment: While this would work, you've turned an O(1) hash access into an O(n) array search

Comment: You're answer is okay (although the problem wasn't with the `#include?` method), but as @FrederickCheung pointed out, you turned the Hash into an Array, **which could cause a sever performance penalty** (depending on Hash size). using the [`#has_key?` method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-has_key-3F) would be better... even using `self[ip].nil?` would be better (although uglier)... please update your answer.

Answer (score 1):

@Piotr has given a good answer to your question. I would like to expand on what he said, considering that you are new to Ruby. First, let's look at your code, slightly modified.

```
class Bans < Hash
  def ban(ip, time, reason)
    puts "self before self[#{ip}]= #{self}"
    self[ip] = {time: time, reason: reason}
    puts "self after self[#{ip}]= #{self}"
  end

  def banned?(ip)
    keys.include?(ip)
  end
end
```

You have created a class `Bans`, which is a subclass of `Hash`. If we look at:

```
Bans.ancestors
  #=> [Bans, Hash, Enumerable, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

we see that `Bans` inherits all the methods of its ancestors. We can return all of `Bans`' instance methods in array:

```
Bans.instance_methods
   #=> [:ban, :banned?, :rehash,..., :to_h, :__send__, :__id__]
```

On my computer (Ruby v2.2.1), `Bans.instance_methods.size #=> 152`. Sometime its convenient to write:

```
Bans.instance_methods.sort
  #=> [:!, :!=,..., :ban, :banned,..., :values_at, :zip]
```

or

```
Bans.instance_methods.include?(:banned?)
  #=> true
```

You can obtain the instance methods defined on `Bans` (rather than on an ancestor), by adding the argument `false`:

```
Bans.instance_methods(false)
   => [:ban, :banned?]
```

This may also be helpful:

```
Bans.instance_method(:ban).owner
  #=> Bans 
Bans.instance_method(:values_at).owner
  #=> Hash 
Bans.instance_method(:chunk).owner
  #=> Enumerable
```

All this can also be done for determining `Bans`' class methods. Just substitute `method` for `instance_method`. For example:

```
Bans.methods.sort
  # [:!, :!=,...:untrusted?] 

Bans.methods(false)
  #=> [] (since we didn't define any)
```

You see that I've added the lines to print the value of `self` before and after `self[ip] = {time: time, reason: reason}`.

To invoke one of `Bans`' instance methods we need to create an instance of the class:

```
b = Bans.new
  #=> {}
```

and then send the method to the instance:

```
b.ban(:wyatt, 'high noon', 'gunfight')
# self before self[wyatt]= {}
# self after self[wyatt]= {:wyatt=>{:time=>"high noon", :reason=>"gunfight"}}
```

This is almost the same as:

```
b.send(:ban, :wyatt, 'high noon', 'gunfight')
```

which reads, "send the method (or "message") `:ban` with arguments `:wyatt`, `'high noon'`, `'gunfight'` to the instance `b`. I suggest you think of it this way. (Ruby does.) The only difference is that `send` must be a public method to use `b.ban`, but can be a private methods when using `send`.

The key to understanding Ruby is to know what `self` is at different points in your code. I therefore encourage you to salt your code with `puts self` lines.

Next you want to invoke `banned?`. You wrote:

```
def banned?(ip)
  if self.include?(ip)
    return true
  else
    return false
  end
end
```

Let's try it:

```
b.banned?(:wyatt)
  #=> true
b.banned?(:doc)
  #=> false
```

Success! We can, however, simplify.

Firstly, what you have is the same as:

```
def banned?(ip)
  self.include?(ip)
end
```

because `self.include?(ip)` returns `true` or `false`. Now what is `self`? We saw above that it equals:

```
s = {:wyatt=>{:time=>"high noon", :reason=>"gunfight"} }
```

so the operative line of `banned?` evaluates to:

```
s.include?(ip)
```

Does `s` have a method `include?`? Let's find out:

```
s.methods(:include?)
  #=> true
s.method(:include).owner
  #=> Hash
```

so we can lookup the docs for [Hash#include?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-include-3F), which tells us whether `s` has a key `ip`. ([Hash#key?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-key-3F) or [Hash#has_key?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-has_key-3F) do the same. Of the three, I'd say `key?` is used most, `include?`, least.)

Now just one more thing. Suppose we write:

```
def banned?(ip)
  key?(ip)
end
```

The method `key?` has no explicit receiver (formerly `self` was the explicit receiver). When there is no explicit receiver, Ruby assumes it to be `self`. That's why Ruby evaluates `key?(ip)` as `self.key?(ip)`. I suggest you exclued `self.` when it's not needed. A word of warning: sometimes you need to include `self.` to avoid ambiguity. For example, you cannot write:

```
[ip] = {time: time, reason: reason}
```

as the operative line in `ban`. You will learn about that in time.

Answer (score 0):

You got two interesting answers that answer your question.

Now you can create a global static instance of Bans, which you could easily use across your application to review IP bans:

```
class Bans < Hash
  def ban(ip, time = Time.now, reason = nil)
    puts "self before self[#{ip}]= #{self}"
    self[ip] = {time: time, reason: reason}
    puts "self after self[#{ip}]= #{self}"
  end

  def banned?(ip)
    self.include?(ip)
  end
end

#create BANS instance static variable
BANS = Bans.new
```

Now, you can check / set ip bans:

```
#set
BANS.ban '127.0.0.1', Time.now, :test
# check
BANS.banned? '127.0.0.1'
```

**However**, I'm not sure the design for your code is optimal.

Saving banned IP addresses in a variable (static or otherwise) has the following issues:

1. The banned IP list will be lost each time the application restarts.
2. The list isn't scalable (if your application is meant for production, you will not be able to share the list across load-balancing instances of your application).
3. The list might be corrupted in a multi-threaded environment (I don't think you should worry about this, but it's possible).

I would recommend using a database to store the information. If you are using Rails, it should be as easy as adding a model class using the rails generator.

Using a database should help resolve all those issues.